# Changing order of locations on classpath to be loaded up by surefire-plugin

Tags: java, maven-3, surefire

Does anybody know how to change it ?

I mean from

```
target/test-classes ... target/classes .... maven dependencies
```

to

```
target/test-classes ... maven dependencies .... target/classes
```

It relates to this surefire-plugin [feature request](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-667)

It's because surefire-plugin cannot include/exclude resources from /target/classes  ... it can only include/exlude resources via `<testResources>` element which can affect only /target/test-classes, not /target/classes

It all happens here in Surefire-plugin :

```
File projectClassesDirectory = new File( project.getBuild().getOutputDirectory() );
if ( !projectClassesDirectory.equals( classesDirectory ) )
{
    int indexToReplace = classpathElements.indexOf( project.getBuild().getOutputDirectory() );
    if ( indexToReplace != -1 )
    {
        classpathElements.remove( indexToReplace );
        classpathElements.add( indexToReplace, classesDirectory.getAbsolutePath() );
    }
    else
    {
        classpathElements.add( 1, classesDirectory.getAbsolutePath() );
    }
}

File projectTestClassesDirectory = new File( project.getBuild().getTestOutputDirectory() );
if ( !projectTestClassesDirectory.equals( testClassesDirectory ) )
{
    int indexToReplace = classpathElements.indexOf( project.getBuild().getTestOutputDirectory() );
    if ( indexToReplace != -1 )
    {
        classpathElements.remove( indexToReplace );
        classpathElements.add( indexToReplace, testClassesDirectory.getAbsolutePath() );
    }
    else
    {
        classpathElements.add( 0, testClassesDirectory.getAbsolutePath() );
    }
}

getLog().debug( "Test Classpath :" );

for ( Iterator i = classpathElements.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
{
    String classpathElement = (String) i.next();

    getLog().debug( "  " + classpathElement );

    surefireBooter.addClassPathUrl( classpathElement );
}
```

Comment: This smells like you are trying to solve the wrong problem

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyed I'm sure I don't, if you read the JIRA issue, especially last 3 of my comments, I have good reason for it

Comment: @lisak your comments seem to make sense, but the smell remains: There has got to be a better way to achieve what you are trying to do

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyed you see but that is the workaround that implies from absence of the possibility to change resources in /target/classes when testing ... I really don't see why maven guys don't want it there. There are tons of such feature requests. The plugin has a Liferay's code generator, that uses META-INF/ as an output path, but I can't use META-INF when testing because I'm loading resources from dependency:[META-INF/]

Comment: And it's a common maven dependency I cannot classload it myself ... I just have to accept that it has resources I need on this conflicting path ... All that I can do, is copy the resources over to src/test/resources, but it is a Testing Archetype, I can't do that

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us what you're trying to achieve. Changing the classpath order is a means how to get to it which may be ok, but perhaps the 'real' question is much easier to answer?

Comment: We've discussed about that in the feature request. It's quite complicated

Answer (score 1):

Consider testing in a separate project.  In general, when you have a project that conflicts with The Maven Way, that's the solution - split it up.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your feature request link, is that you have some `src/main/resources/config.xml` and a dependency that also contains a `config.xml` that you want to use in your tests. Is that right?

If that is the case, what you could do is to move your `src/main/resources/config.xml` to another place (not a resource dir), like `src/config/config.xml` and them include it in your final JAR/WAR by setting the [war](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) or [jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#includes) plugin config.

In that way your tests will see the `config.xml` from your dependency but not your `src/config/config.xml` since it is not in the classpath.